# What's the meaning of "self-spoken"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Character Information
>
> ...
>
> Personality
>
> Mean, abusive, prejudiced, self-spoken

(http://zootopia.wikia.com/wiki/Woodchuck_bully)

Comment: It's not a meaningful phrase in English; I think it's an error on that page.  "Soft-spoken" is meaningful, but that would seem to contradict "mean, abusive," so I have no idea what the page's author intended.

Comment: Google Books has references to things like [*a self-spoken lesbian*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22self-spoken+lesbian%22), which I assume is a "copying error" based on half-remembered ***self-confessed***. I also found [*A self-spoken, retiring demeanor isn't an illustrator's best approach*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22self-spoken+retiring%22), which is obviously just a typo/OCR error for ***soft-spoken***. Clearly neither are applicable in the exact context cited here, which I think is just a non-native speaker who didn't know to use ***self-opinionated***.

Comment: A word that would fit into that list is **outspoken**.

Comment: **self-spoken** isn't a character-trait.

Answer (score -1):

I haven´t found an specific dictionary entry for **self-spoken** but

According to Cambridge Dictionary

[**self-**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/self) [PREFFIX]

> **of** or by yourself or itself

[**-spoken**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spoken) [SUFFIX]

> **speaking** in a particular way

And according to MacMillan

[**self**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/self_1)

> a. [UNCOUNTABLE] **SPOKEN**
>
> what you feel and want, rather than what other
>   people feel and want

Adding all these evidences with the other characteristics you listed, we can infer that he's a person that is always talking about himself.

EDITED: I'm not a native English speaker, it has been pointed that "self-spoken" is not a 
recognizable word. Maybe the author of the entry meant [self-centred](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/self-centred) or any of its synonyms.